# constant function with non-zero derivative almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can I have a function which is a constant function, but has a derivative of say 1 almost everywhere?

EDIT: I was trying to stay away of notation, but it seems as if this is very much necessary. I've edited the whole question so that it is hopefully more formally described.

My construction is the following:

You have a periodic function, say a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), and we decrease the period without changing the slope, this would reduce the amplitude, which can be made as small as desired.

Maybe more formally, this could be expressed as:

Starting with the pulse train of period 1 defined as:

$$ f(t) = \delta(sin(\frac \pi{2} t)) $$

We can obtain a sawtooth wave by integrating this as:

$$ g(t) = \int_0^t [1 - \delta(sin(\frac \pi{2} \tau))]  d\tau $$

The maximum value this function g(t) can reach is 1, as, when it hits this value, the next $\delta $ will be present and will push the value of the function down.

Finally, we introduce our desired constraint which is to increase the frequency of the pulse train and reduce the maximum value of the function:

$$ h(t) = lim_{k \to 0}(\int_0^t [1 - k\delta(sin(\frac \pi{2k} \tau))]  d\tau) $$

So $d{h(t)}/{dt}$ should be just:

$$ \frac{dh(t)}{dt} = 1 - lim_{k \to 0}(k\int_0^t\delta(sin(\frac \pi{2k} \tau))]  d\tau) $$

But k is vanishing towards zero, however the deltas pose a problem here.

I hope I made myself understood.

EDIT2: The way I understand this type of construction geometrically is like that of a [fresnel lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens#/media/File:Fresnel_lens.svg) and in my understanding should allow any function with any integral/derivative by using this trick, but I didn't want to complicate the question too much.

Comment: "Constant" means that in some interval (can also be all the real numbers) the given function has the same value. And of course, in this interval, the derivate is then $0$. Pathological functions (like the function that is $1$ for rational numbers and $0$ else) are not constant.

Comment: While this isn't possible, the reverse (a continuous nonconstant function with zero derivative almost everywhere) is.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you mean Cantor staircase, right? I was inspired by that. Would you care to elaborate in why this isn't possible? Is my definition of constant, not good?

Comment: Why do this have that many downvotes? Please someone explain it to me...

Comment: @hermis14 I was wondering the same, but I guess I don't mind. People can get really passionate over technical fields when they disagree with you. I just wish they told me why!

Comment: The trouble is, you are implicitly using some nonstandard definition of a "constant" function, and you did not spell out what your definition is. At least some downvotes are probably due to this. Also, none of what you wrote after the second sentence is a coherent math.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I tried to write down more precisely what I meant, but this a part of the problem. I hope now you would consider it coherent math. 
The way I understand this construction, a function created like this is a type of "constant" function. The other possibility is that the integral is like a convolution (like green's function ) type of thing and I am just plain wrong and it evaluates to a finite number. 
Peter mentions a function which is like this kind, but not exactly like this one, because it has 2 different values, my construction has a limit which goes to zero.

Comment: @user27221: Your post remains as unclear as before. Judging by your writing, your are a physicist, which would explain the difficulty you have communicating math. I think, you are even misunderstanding the word "definition", as it is used by mathematicians. My advice, at this point would be to forget about your question, pick up, say, Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" (or another rigorous introduction to analysis) and read few chapters, work through problems. In the process, you will learn how math works, e.g. what does it take to give a clear definition or/and a proof.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your construction is the following: Take $f_T(\theta)=\cos(\frac{\theta}{T})$, with $T\in(0,\infty)$. Then the process of "taking the period to zero" would be to take $f=\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}f_T$. The problem is: How do you calculate $y=f(\theta)=\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}f_T(\theta)$ for a fixed $\theta$? You can't, because the limit doesn't exist ever, except for $\theta=0$, and it doesn't exist because it depends on how you approach $0$: For example, if you approach $0$ with the sequence $T=\frac{\theta}{n\pi}$, you get $$f(\theta)=\lim_{T\rightarrow0}\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$$which does not have a limit (which is already enough to conclude that $\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}f_T(\theta)$ doesn't exist), but if you use $\frac{\theta}{2\pi n}$, then the sequence is constantly $=1$. You can see also from the picture: If you take $T$ to zero, the result is that over every point you should have an entire *interval* of values.

Now, as said in the comments, the problem is not with the construction you presented, but with the aim itself. There's no way to construct a constant map with non-zero derivative (not even almost everywhere). The differential of a constant map is zero. Even if you consider the weak derivative of a constant map, this will be zero almost everywhere (so this property of being zero on constant maps is not only for the strong derivative).

**Edit** If you constrain the values of the function and then make these go to zero, then the limit function will be constant. However, derivatives are extremely ill-behaved when it comes to limits. Even if your convergence is uniform, the derivative of the result will not be the limit of the derivatives.

Unless you change your notion of derivative, this problem is set: A constant function will have zero derivative.

Comment: You are neglecting one of the constraints which was that the amplitude would also diminish, so your limit is not correct, as the frequency increases, the amplitude of the wave decreases, so there is an upper and lower bound that I can place that constraint the function value

Comment: Your edit doesn't solve the problem with your formulation limit of sinx when x goes to infinity and 1/x*sinx are complete different things and the last one has a derivative that goes to zero, while sinx doesn't

Comment: Then please write down explicitly your construction. Namely, not just "saying" what you're doing, but actually giving formulas, limits and such. Motivate such statements as "[...] the likelihood of getting one of them is comparable to that of hitting a sloped part". Also, specify what definition of derivative you're using, because a differentiable function is always continuous, so to be able to differentiate "singular" functions you can't use the strong notion of derivative

Comment: Then take the statement "So a further step to describe how far apart those discontinuities are is placing them every rational number" and clarify. From "to describe how far apart those discontinuities are" it seems that the discontinuities are already there, so why say "placing them every rational number", which means that you control them. Also, what is your definition of slope? You mean like a Lipschitz constant?

Comment: I removed that argument, because it was not necessary and probably wrong. I can show the same weirdness without it and I rewrote the question to show it. My point with your answer is that you understood my construction only partially. Using a mathematical analogy, you understood something like the behaviour around zero of $sin(100/x)$ and I meant $xsin(100/x) $

Answer (score 0):

You are in good company here.  This idea of taking a limit of little sawtooth functions and deducing some weird fact about derivatives is, of course, totally misguided but evidence of a fertile imagination and maybe even greatness to come.

The famous Russian analyst N. N. Luzin (1883–1950) made exactly the same error when he was a young student.

He recounted in a letter [reproduced in Amer. Math. Monthly, 107, (2000), pp. 64–82] how he offered this argument to his professor after a lecture on the Weierstrass continuous nowhere differentiable function.

> “It seems to me that one can construct a curve without a tangent in
> a very elementary way. We divide the diagonal of a square into n equal
> parts and onstruct on each subdivision as base a right isosceles
> triangle. In this way we get a kind of delicate little saw. Now I put
> n = ∞. The saw becomes a continuous curve that is infinitesimally
> different from the diagonal. But it is perfectly clear that its
> tangent is alternately parallel now to the x-axis, now to the
> y-axis.”

Some of us might claim that the sign of a good mathematician is not the size of his reprint pile, but the amount of garbage he has scribbled and thrown away.